# Sending/Uploading Files through APIs - .Net Core

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to send a file through an API. The server will receive the file and save it on the server drive.
The question is that I have two Options to do this:

1. Read the file as a string and send the whole string in the request Body
2. Use multi-part

Could someone help in the pros and cons in using the two options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to pros and cons, So basically to understand what is multipart means

> Multipart requests combine one or more sets of data into a single
> body, separated by boundaries. You typically use these requests for
> file uploads and for transferring data of several types in a single
> request (for example, a file along with a JSON object).

This mean that multipart contains different section of info that separated by boundary(random number).

For example:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 428
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=abcde12345
--abcde12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"
Content-Type: text/plain
{...Additional plain content goes here...}
--abcde12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "street": "3, Garden St",
  "city": "Hillsbery, UT"
}
--abcde12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileImage "; filename="image1.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
{...file content...}
--abcde12345--
```

In this example you can see different content sent in one request separated by boundary [boundary=abcde12345]. (Plain text, Json Object and File Content)

The file content section here is used for sending file data in ***application/octet-stream*** (string in the binary or base64 format), so basically you are sending the file data in form of string :) as you referred to the first point, but you can include some additional info, may be the new file name to be saved , the user who uploaded this file or whatever you want.

Hope you get the point.

Ref:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/

Answer (score 0):

The only difference on the protocol level is that multipart/form-data requests must adhere to [RFC 2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) while a custom typed request body can be arbitrary.

Using Base64 string has an advantage for uploading very tiny individual images. It's easy to handle and avoids dependency on Http.IFormFile. On the contrary, base64 encoded files are larger than the original and you need decode it on the server side.